# How to optimize lazy loading of related object, if we already have its instance?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-queryset, django-orm

I like how Django ORM lazy loads related objects in the queryset, but I guess it's quite unpredictable as it is.
The queryset API doesn't keep the related objects when they are used to make a queryset, thereby fetching them again when accessed later.

Suppose I have a **ModelA** instance (say *instance_a*) which is a foreign key (say *for_a*) of some N instances of **ModelB**. Now I want to perform query on **ModelB** which has the given **ModelA** instance as the foreign key.

Django ORM provides two ways:

- Using `.filter()` on **ModelB**:

```py
b_qs = ModelB.objects.filter(for_a=instance_a)
for instance_b in b_qs:
    instance_b.for_a # <-- fetches the same row for ModelA again
```

Results in 1 + N queries here.

- Using reverse relations on **ModelA** instance:

```py
b_qs = instance_a.for_a_set.all()
for instance_b in b_qs:
    instance_b.for_a # <-- this uses the instance_a from memory
```

Results in 1 query only here.

While the second way can be used to achieve the result, it's not part of the standard API and not useable for every scenario. For example, if I have instances of 2 foreign keys of **ModelB** (say, **ModelA** and **ModelC**) and I want to get related objects to both of them.
Something like the following works:

```
ModelB.objects.filter(for_a=instance_a, for_c=instance_c)
```

I guess it's possible to use `.intersection()` for this scenario, but I would like a way to achieve this via the standard API. After all, covering such cases would require more code with non-standard queryset functions which may not make sense to the next developer.

So, the first question, is it possible to optimize such scenarios with the the standard API itself?
The second question, if it's not possible right now, can it be added with some tweaks with the QuerySet?

**PS:** It's my first time asking a question here, so forgive me if I made any mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You could improve the query by using [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
b_qs = ModelB.objects.select_related('for_a').filter(for_a=instance_a)
```

or

```
b_qs = instance_a.for_a_set.select_related('for_a')
```

Does that help?

Comment: That will perform join on that SQL query, making it more complex than it needs to be. After all, I already have *instance_a* in memory and even using it when constructing a queryset; it doesn't make sense to fetch its data via SQL again.

Comment: @shivanshs9 Then don't access `instance_b.for_a` if you already have `instance_a`, so no new query will be made.

Comment: @shivanshs9: the Django ORM is not like SqlAlchemy that indeed has some logic for existing loaded objects (this has some problems w.r.t. mutability as well).

Comment: @shivanshs9: furthermore you could also use `for_a=id_of_instancea`. The objects that originate from a queryset are not really aware where these originated from, and thus these do not "use" that information. That could indeed save some queries, but it would make generating queries and interpreting the results more expensive.

Comment: @Ralf Actually, it's a practical use-case in some of my DRF Serializers. I fetched the instance_a in the API view to check permissions and then serialized some related objects which had a need of using instance_a again.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh, I wasn't aware the SQLAlchemy has that feature. And I'm not really talking about already-loaded objects, like what [Identity Map](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html) is for, since I know how it gets very complex.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not sure how it would make interpreting the results expensive though.. since that's what reverse relationship has already fixed, right?

Answer (score 1):

You use [**`.select_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for `ForeignKey`s, or [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for something-to-many relations.

With `.select_related(..)` you will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` at the database side, and fetch records for the two objects, and thus do the deserialization to the proper objects.

```
ModelB.objects.select_related('for_a').filter(for_a=instance_a)
```

For relations that are one-to-many (so a reversed `ForeignKey`), or `ManyToManyField`s, this is not a good idea, since it could result in a large amount of duplicate objects that are retrieved. This would result in a large answer from the database, and a lot of work at the Python end to deserialize these objects. `.prefetch_related` will make individual queries, and then do the linking itself.